# How to RANDOM() select the first/least/... row per group in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample data:

```
id|category_id|name
--------------
1|1|test 1
2|1|test 2
3|1|test 3
4|2|test 4
5|2|test 5
6|2|test 6
```

And mysql

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.category_id 
FROM `test` AS p 
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM `test` f WHERE f.category_id = p.category_id AND f.id <= p.id) <= 2 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

And result is:

```
1|1|test 1
2|1|test 2
4|2|test 4
5|2|test 5
```

=> But result can't RANDOM() value to get other value(id=3 and id=6), how to fix it ?

Comment: What are the first/least/max rows you want to get from the sample data you posted? add them please.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: how to random result all id

Answer (score 0):

try this.. put the RAND in where clause not in ORDER BY...

> SELECT p.id, p.name, p.category_id  FROM `test` AS p  WHERE (SELECT
>   count(*) FROM `test` f WHERE f.category_id = p.category_id AND f.id <=
>   p.id) <= 2  AND RAND() <= 6